# Parser bracket regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm copletly noob of regex, but i'm forced to use it.

I've tried to read other topics about regex butI still have some questios

I have string like this:

```
a(b(c))d
```

And I'd like it after while loop to show me something like this:

```
c
b(c)
```

I've tried to work with

```
Regex r = new Regex("/{\"(:\":\"(.*?)\")/");
```

But it did't work at all

Also can you please recomend me any tutorial or book from where can I lear about regular expressions?

Thanks in advance
Radek

Comment: Any reason you're trying to match a `{` in your regex, when that char doesn't show up in your sample text at all?

Comment: So you want to extract whatever is in matched parentheses, starting from the innermost?

Comment: Your regex has nothing to do with the input you want to match. Are you sure you posted the right one?

Comment: I would forget about regexp and solve this with a simple recursive function! If you want arbitrary nesting in the expression regexp will never work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using regular expressions to do this than I would suggest first going over some tutorials, like [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

In addition, it looks like you are trying to match any parameters within a string, in that case I would suggest reading [This Article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/regexp/thread/3768bbb8-e95d-493e-8698-6d760e46dbd0/) which describes what looks like a similar scenario.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to learn more about regular expressions, head to http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Regular expressions and parsing have a [crippled relationship at best](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html) when dealing with nested content.

Since the pattern you are looking at could go arbitrarily deep, you would need something that can understand the placement of each bracket.